# Disable certain Combination Variations

Tags: expresso-store

So, my first time round with expresso store.

What i'm hoping to do is limit certain combinations of variations, as well as change the price for combinations.

The products are custom made so the materials and dimensions affect the price.

Here's an example.

```
Item      Size      Material     Price
Table     300mm     Mahogany     £250.00
Table     500mm     Plywood      £200.00
Table     500mm     Mahogany     N/A
```

Also, need to be able to display a message dependant on the combination, too - tho I can probably do that easiest by detecting the price (as there will be many variation options, there will be few price variations).

Anyway, will appreciate any and all help, if the answer is 'build an extension to do it' that's fine - just don't want to get into all that if I just don't need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need to write an extension to handle something like this because currently if you have 2 modifier groups "Size" and "Material" you would set how each modifier in each group effects the price individually.

Basically if 300mm added £50 it would add that and then if Mahogany added an additional £50 that would be selected. In a situation where I selected 500mm and Mahogany it would still only add £50 for the Mahogany selection and then whatever you have set the price for 500mm.

You should be able to use the limit stock option however to prevent certain configurations from being selected.

Comment: That's kinda what I thought, thanks. Custom here we go!